# Springfox Swagger generates fields not in the method signature

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I enabled springfox swagger for my spring boot application. Here is the code setup

**SwaggerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**")).build().apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData()
    {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("myApp REST API", "REST APIs for myApp", "1.0.0", "", new Contact("", "", ""), "Proprietary", "", Collections
                .emptyList());
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RestController
public class UserApiController
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Secured(value = { "ROLE_ADMIN", "PERMISSION_LIST_USERS" })
    @GetMapping(value = "/list", produces = "application/json")
    List<UserBO> listUsers(HttpSession session)
    {
        Long companyId = (Long) session.getAttribute("companyId");
        List<UserBO> users = userService.listUsers(companyId);
        return users;
    }

    @Secured(value = { "ROLE_ADMIN", "PERMISSION_USER_CREATE" })
    @PostMapping("/create")
    ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam Long usergroupId, HttpSession session)
    {
        Long companyId = (Long) session.getAttribute("companyId");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = userService
                .createUser(login, password, firstName, lastName, usergroupId, companyId);
        return response;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here is the swagger ui I see

[image]

There are a lot of other parameters that are not in the method signature (**creationTime, lastAccessedTime** etc).

Why is swagger generating those and how do I prevent it and have only the params in the method signature generated?

Comment: Because you have HttpSession as a method param.

Comment: @AlanHay you are right, when I removed the HttpSession parameter the entries were gone, how do I hide or make it not appear in the api doc

Comment: Figured it out, add the @ApiIgnore annotation for the HttpSession parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, as @AlanHay has pointed out, the other parameters were showing because the `HttpSession` object was in the method signature and in order to ignore that I had to use the `@ApiIgnore` annotation for the `HttpSession` parameter in the method signature.

So the method would be

```
@Secured(value = { "ROLE_ADMIN", "PERMISSION_LIST_USERS" })
@GetMapping(value = "/list", produces = "application/json")
List<UserBO> listUsers(@ApiIgnore HttpSession session)
{
    Long companyId = (Long) session.getAttribute("companyId");
    List<UserBO> users = userService.listUsers(companyId);
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding Docket bean configuration :

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.springbackend.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex(".*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaData());
     }
```

Comment: I've already added that, you mean change it to RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.springbackend.controller"), I've tried those as well